# Getting error in Angular 6 Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angular6

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at levenshtein (F:\Learnings\AngularHandsOn\Angular6\angular6Handson\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:58:23)
    at listAllCommandNames.sort (F:\Learnings\AngularHandsOn\Angular6\angular6Handson\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:69:43)
    at Array.sort (native)
    at Object. (F:\Learnings\AngularHandsOn\Angular6\angular6Handson\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:67:65)
    at Generator.next ()
    at F:\Learnings\AngularHandsOn\Angular6\angular6Handson\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:7:71
    at new Promise ()
    at __awaiter (F:\Learnings\AngularHandsOn\Angular6\angular6Handson\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:3:12)
    at Object.runCommand (F:\Learnings\AngularHandsOn\Angular6\angular6Handson\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:28:12)
    at F:\Learnings\AngularHandsOn\Angular6\angular6Handson\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js:60:58

When I am directly pasting url in browser then all are working fine even its not showing any error in console window. But when I use ng -o command then it shows me error.

I am using angular cli 6.0.0

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error & it took me hours to resolve because the error was misleading to me, it was actually because I tried these 2 incorrect commands:

```
ng -build -prod
ng -build --prod
```

Both of the above commands gave that error, so I thought I have a problem in my code & kept looking for it, **the solution was simply to use the correct command below:**

```
ng build --prod
```

Comment: I had the same error as the OP. It is from using an incorrect CLI commmand.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, that this error appears, when wrong argument is used. Try to use

```
ng serve -o
```

Comment: Correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also received this error when I forgot to change templateUrl to template in the @Component decorator after moving a template from an external file to inline.