# Angular 6 ng build Cannot read property 'length' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at levenshtein

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have found this error [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50306105/7588447) but it was not resolved, so I am asking if someone can help me troubleshoot this:

I am using Angular 6 & if I use `ng s` the application runs locally perfectly fine, also using
 `ng s --aot` works fine, however, if I build a production build from angular I get the error below without any reference to the reason of it (within my code)

Note:
I have already successfully made multiple prod builds before

How to find which variable or property is causing this?

Thanks

```
ng -build -prod
    Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
        at levenshtein (D:Angular\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:58:23)
        at listAllCommandNames.sort (D:Angular\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:69:43)
        at Array.sort (native)
        at Object.<anonymous> (D:Angular\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:67:65)
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at D:Angular\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:7:71
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at __awaiter (D:Angular\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:3:12)
        at Object.runCommand (D:Angular\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:28:12)
        at D:Angular\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js:60:58
```

Comment: Please explain if you downvote the question how I can improve it, thanks

Comment: I think command should be `ng build --prod`.

Comment: @hrdkisback that was the issue actually , thanks a million, it took me hours as the error was very misleading and I thought my code was accessing a null initialized array

You can make an answer & I will upvote you , many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to hrdkisback excellent comment I found out the issue

I got the same error & it took me hours to resolve because the error was misleading to me, it was actually because I tried these 2 incorrect commands:

```
ng -build -prod
ng -build --prod
```

Both of the above commands gave that error, so I thought I have a problem in my code & kept looking for it, **the solution was simply to use the correct command below:**

```
ng build --prod
```